# Minikube not able to reach vault via curl for auto-authentication agent configuration

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

For some task, i am following the below example to configure the HashiCorp Vault auto Auth agent with minikube.

```
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/agent-kubernetes?in=vault/app-integration
```

In the section “Determine the Vault address” step 3.
i am trying to execute the below curl command to check connectivity:

```
curl http://192.168.1.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status
```

and getting below error"

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.1 port 8200: Connection refused
```

While i check the connectivity between host machine(Windows10 and minikube route with gateway value of 0.0.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this error might be due to you are running curl at windows 10 while your container running inside minikube.

You can do port-forward or you can use the bridge connection IP to connect with vault.

You can setup one extra pod `busybox` in minikube and use the curl from there so that it will connect to vault on same network, in minikube you can also talk over the **service name** instead of IP.

you can follow this guide and look for port-forwarding option also.

```
 kubectl port-forward vault-0 8200:8200
```

once port are forwarded to local you can `curl locahost:8200` instead of IP.

**Get vault service** :

```
kubectl get svc -n <Namespace name>
```

**Port forward to local machine**

```
 kubectl port-forward <service name> 8200:8200 -n <Namespace name>
```

**Curl localhost**

```
curl localhost:8200/v1/sys/seal-status
```